# Как после вызова нового activity уничтожить прошлый?

Tags: java, activity, android-intent

При вызове нового активити хочу запретить переход на прошлый (то есть уничтожать все прошлые активности). Переход по кнопке назад уже сделал с помощью `onBackPressed()`. Но при выходе из приложения все равно перекидывает на первую активность. Вроде это можно сделать с помощью `finish` или `onDestroy`, но не понимаю как. Вот часть кода

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.answer1:
            int ans1 = Integer.parseInt(enter1.getText().toString());
            if (k1==ans1){
            Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
            }
```

Comment: А покажите код который сейчас есть. А точнее активити с которого происходит переход и которое нужно уничтожить. И желательно те варианты которые уже пробовали использовать.

Comment: вы не можете уничтожить активность никаким доступным программисту способом, вы можете закрыть ее командой finish() и тогда при уборке мусора она будет уничтожена. НО! судя по всему речь идет о стеке переходов, в таком случае даже уничтоженая она будет восстановлена при переходах. Вам нужно работать с самим стеком переходов, а не пытаться убивать процессы. В вопросе не ясна задача, что именно и когда должно происходить. PS: *"вроде можно сделать .."* - документация в свободном доступе, там однозначно сказано, что тот или иной метод будет делать. onDestroy() - колбэк, реакция на действие

Comment: Если речь идет о "холодном" перезапуске, то приложение всегда будет запущенно со стартовой активити. Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы было однозначно ясно, в чем именно проблема, без этих вот всех "вроде что то где то не так.."